# Need help for a trouble with Keil C window

Tags: arm, stm32f4, keil

I tried to program STM32 with Keil C but when I try to "Set Path" to the library, there is a problem like this:

[image]

As you can see, the "Option for Target" window doesn't show all everything, there is something on the right side but I cannot see it. I tried with KeilC4, KeilC5, and the problem persist. I cannot zoom in/enlarge this window. I guess I need to adjust something in my computer but I don't know what to do. Can anyone help me? This happens to all the other windows in KeilC.

Comment: stretch the window

Comment: It looks like a windows Application GUI issue with scalable Windows therme fonts but non-scalable flash app window.  try another theme or undo any Personalization font settings or try another user.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: the window in KeilC is not stretchable. I don't think the problem is about the KeilC but about my computer because in the past, this problem didn't happen

Answer (score 0):

> I tried with KeilC4, KeilC5, and the problem persist.

I can only tell you that it works perfectly for uvision v4.